# Is it that these two polynomials doesn't have a common zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots

Consider $x$ a vector of $n$ components (complex). Now consider the following two polynomial equations.

- $x^TPx-1=0$ where $P$ is an $n\times n$ squared matrix.
- $q(x)=0$ with $q(x)$ a polynomial of degree greater than 2 and homogenenous of degree $\alpha$, i.e. $q(tx)=t^\alpha q(x), t>0$.

**I wanted to study the common zeros of these two equations, however I noticed something strange.**

Write these two polynomials as

- $x^TPx- 1 = p(x)r(x)$
- $q(x) = s(x)r(x)$

where $p,r,s$ are polynomials. $r(x)$ is a polynomial which vanish at the common zeros of $x^TPx-1$ and $q(x)$. Moreover and $p,s$ doesn't vanish when $r(x)$ vanishes. Now pick any $y$ such that $r(y)=0$ and choose $x = ty$ for $t>0$ in order to study the rational function $q(x)/(x^TPx-1)$. Then,
$$
\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{q(x)}{x^TPx-1}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{s(x)}{p(x)} = \lim_{t\to 1}\frac{s(ty)}{p(ty)}=L
$$
where $L\neq 0$ since $p(ty)<\infty$ for any $t$ near 1 (since $p(y)$ its a polynomial) and $s(y)\neq 0$. However,
$$
\frac{q(x)}{x^TPx-1}=\frac{q(ty)}{t^2y^TPy-1} = \frac{t^\alpha }{t^2-1}q(y)=0
$$
for any $t\neq 1$ since $q(y)=0$ and $y^TPy=1$. Hence, I arrive at a contradiction:  inspecting $q(x)/(x^TPx-1)$ in terms of $s/p$ I obtain that it must be different to 0 near $x=y$. However, by inspecting $q(x)/(x^TPx-1)$ directly I obtain that it must be zero near $x=y$. Hence, I cannot write them as $x^TPx-1=p(x)r(x)$ and $q(x) = p(x)r(x)$ so they do not have the common factor $r(x)$. Therefore they don't share any common solution.

However, I thought polynomial systems of equations always had (complex) solutions. I never assumed that the common factor $r(x)$ vanished somewhere at the real line, so I don't know where my procedure failed.

**So, is it that these two polynomial equations share a common zero? If so, whats the flaw in my argument? Is my procedure correct?**

Hopefully, I made some stupid error, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only for polynomials in a single variable that solutions must lead to factors of the polynomial.  It certainly doesn't happen in this case.

If $q(x)$ is homogeneous, the factor $r(x)$ must also be homogeneous of its degree.  So either $r$ is constant or $r(0)=0$, and therefore can't be a factor of $x^T P x - 1$.

It may help to look at a simple example:
$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.  The common solutions are $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$, $y=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$.  But $x^2-y^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ have no common factors.

Comment: Ok, so having common factors is not a necessary condition to have common solutions, I guess...? Thanks sir.

Comment: Just read the first sentence you added. Everything is now clear. Thanks!